# Matching cost of load balancer while exporting billing to Big Query (GOOGLE CLOUD)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, billing

I was not able to match the cost of the load balancer while I was exporting the billing to a big query. I could not get the proper SKU (ID and description).

I've tried putting the labels in frontend service of load balancer but not getting the proper SKU ID to match the cost of it.

i want the specific sku id so i can match the cost

Comment: You can lookup SKUs here: https://cloud.google.com/skus?hl=en